# Change other script's variable and destroy GameObject Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my **platform game** I have just added some **checkpoints,** so that if the player dies doesn't necessarily spawn at the beginning of the track. 
ghfdghdggfhfg
    using UnityEngine;

```
public class CheckPoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Grounded game;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, 5);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter() {
        game.updatedCheckPointPosition = transform.position;
        Destroy(this);
    }
}
```

What I unsuccessfully tried to do is to set the public float variable of the `Grounded` script to the current position of the `CheckPoint` itself, which should be destroyed after doing that.

Any information or help on how to do this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)

> The object `obj` will be destroyed now or if a time is specified `t` seconds from now.
>
> - **If `obj` is a `Component`** it will remove the component from the `GameObject` and destroy it. 
>   [But keep the rest of the GameObject intact!]
> - **If `obj` is a `GameObject`** it will destroy the `GameObject`, all its components and all transform children of the `GameObject`.

`this` refers to the according component instance. What you want is rather

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

---

[`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) requires a parameter of type `Collider` in order to work

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    game.updatedCheckPointPosition = transform.position;
    Destroy(this);
}
```

Note however that this way round the **player** has to be a **trigger** while the **checkpoint** a **non-trigger**! I would actually rather do it the other way round and make the chackpoint a trigger and rather let the player object check for `OnTriggerEnter`.

Comment: thank you, and how can i set the new spawn position?

Comment: It looks like it does not even activate the trigger. I have a sphere with trigger enabled. I don't have any errors on setting the position.

Comment: @EnricoCortinovis Updated the answer

Comment: yes, I followed all the edits :) I'll try to do as you said, set the player as a trigger instead!

Comment: I've tried some different methods now, testing with a few Debug.Log messages here and there, and it just **does not collide with the sphere collider** in any way, but instead works with a box collider 2D. I've just realized that it probably is because one collider is 2D and the other one 3D! :) Anyway now, when the Player character's trigger collides with a gameobject, it checks the tag name, and if it is equal to "CheckPoint", it sets the new _**updatedCheckPointPosition**_ to the player's current position (as i did not manage to set it to the **checkpoint's position** instead.

Comment: oh well yes! Physics3D and Physics2D are totally independent in Unity and there is no chance that 3D stuff can interact with 2D colliders!

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out how to destroy the CheckPoint gameobject right after setting the new spawn position! Could you help me on that? Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199930/discussion-between-enrico-cortinovis-and-derhugo).